# How can I have VIM always display the current block hierarchy?

Tags: vim

```
class Foo
  class Bar
    # many lines
    # many lines
    # many lines
    # many lines
    CURSOR
    # many lines
    # many lines
  end
end
```

If the line "class Bar" is currently outside of the screen, I'd like to have the current blocks' head still visible. Or, better yet, a hierarchical form like so:

```
class Foo > class Bar > current method/function
```

**How can I achieve that in VIM?**

Comment: take a look the tagbar plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that through plugins, of which I suggest two:

1. [tagbar](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar/wiki) plugin, as already suggested by @Kent.
2. [vim-airline](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline) plugin with tagbar extension enabled.

This, together with ctags, Vim will always show your current context in the right side of your status line.